# Returns Nth Element from the List in Reverse Order

Tags: python, list

How to write a function `fifth_element` that takes every fifth element from the list in reverse order and returns a list of elements?

For example:

```
def fifth_element(some_list: list) -> list:
    ...


some_list = ['e',6,8,'A','>','^','S','$','R','C',6,'+','#',9,'/',1,'T','!','%','K',7,'-','O','*','<',2,'h',4,'g']
```

Comment: `some_list[::-5]` ?

Comment: To be clear, what is the desired result for your example? [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73740220/edit) your question.

Comment: Don't be fancy about this, just write a loop that calculates the index of the next relevant element.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fifth_element(my_list):
    return my_list[len(my_list)::-5]
```

The Len(my_list) allows you to get the total length of the list and the splicing notation is stating that you want to go from the back of the list to the front of the list at the order of -5 each time